# ensureIndex for all collections in databases

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Have I to run ensureIndex command multiple times

```
db.collection1.ensureIndex({ <key>: 1})
db.collection2.ensureIndex({ <key>: 1})
db.collection3.ensureIndex({ <key>: 1})
```

or is there a way to run ensureIndex for all collections in databases?

```
db.collectionX.ensureIndex({ <key>: 1})
```

Comment: All your collections will have index on the same key?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that indexes are fairly expensive in terms of RAM and Disk, they hurt the insert performance and the update performance, plus it doesn't make sense to index certain fields (e.g. full text, large byte arrays, etc.). Using a ton of indexes is usually a very bad sign. If you need copied collections (like log data by day or something, which is the only use case I can think of), the code that is responsible for determining the collection should be able to perform the ensure index on that one newly created collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, you still can't do that.

When designing a database there are usually two phases:

1. Create all collections and then run the `ensureIndex` command on each collection. This is done only once unless you migrate your database in which case you might need to run again your `ensureIndex` commands.
2. The second phase is editing the collections structure (improving database, removing fields, adding fields). After you've edited some fields they might also need some indexes or require editing some existing indexes. In this case you usually drop and create other indexes. Still this command is ran only once.

In conclusion there aren't many cases in which devs or admins would need to run `ensureIndex` on multiple collections so many times that they would need one command to change all indexes. Even if there would be such cases, what are the chances that those collections need same indexes?